# Removing @variable slows query

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

i have some code that runs really slow when a variable is NOT defined. I can't leave the variable in the code as it is going to into PowerBi and it doesnt recognise variables, but when i remove it the query times out.

I have searched all day can not find anything, i was hoping someone could help. Query below.

```
select s.date,si.name, coalesce(gics_sector,si.security_type),  @weight := s.market_value / fundval.val, p.name, si.currency, t1.div_yield
from matilda.security_info si
left join(select * from matilda.synth_exp where date = WORKDAY_ADD(current_date(),-1)) as s on si.ticker = s.ticker
left join (select fund_id, sum(market_value), sum(synth_value) as val, date from matilda.synth_exp where date = WORKDAY_ADD(current_date(),-1) group by fund_id,date) as fundval on fundval.fund_id = s.fund_id
left join (select * from matilda.stocks where date = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))) as gics on gics.id = si.id
left join (select * from matilda.dailies where date = WORKDAY_ADD(current_date(),-1)) as t1 on t1.id = si.id
left join matilda.portfolio p on p.fund_id = s.fund_id
where s.market_value is not null;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're saying the posted query works, but if you leave out "@weight :=" then it times out? That would indeed be strange!

Comment: Exactly! Everything I have searched online related to variables slowing things down not speeding them up. Any ideas?

Comment: Are s.market_value and fundval.val guaranteed to be non-NULL and fundval.val guaranteed to be non-zero?

Comment: S.market_value can be null but fundval.val will always have a value. Should I filter the nulls out beforehand?

Comment: Actually, my bad, NULLs shouldn't make a difference. Are you sure fundval.val is never 0? This is really strange - just because I know how easy it is to mistype something, would you mind testing one more time and adding the query that times out?

Comment: Also: If the problem really is about performance, make sure you have proper [indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) added to columns in your WHERE and ON clauses (like date, fund_id, ticker)

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Also, edit clarifications into your post, not comments.

Comment: @E.Villiger I think you have solved it. When i remove the 'where s.market_value is not null' and the "@weight :=" variable declaration it runs fast again. Does declaring a variable create an index?

Comment: @philipxy sorry, this is only the second question i have ever posted ('it's my first day'). i will read the link and clean up the question now

Comment: Once you show us all your code we can talk of indexes. ([Include text as text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097)) (Note that `a left join b where b.x is not null` is just `a inner join b where b.x is not null`, and for x declared `not null` it's just `a inner join b`. (`a left join b` is inner join rows plus unmatched a rows extended by nulls.) So you don't seem to understand left join, so your whole query comes under suspicion and we can't expect to even know what result you want since you didn't describe it any other way. PS Why assign weight? It's nondeterministic.